# Magento 2 price attribute does not have "Use default value" checkbox

Tags: magento2

I'm facing this issue "Price attribute does not have Use Default Value checkbox"

Step:

1. Login to BE
2. Choose the product to Edit
3. Switch to specific store, ex: UK store
4. Look at the Price Attribute

Please refer to the below image that I attached.
How do I show the Use Default Value checkbox on Price Attribute? Is there any config that helps me to do this?

[image: Price attribute does not have Use Default Value checbox]

**My store version: M2.3.5-p1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't set price like that.**

You can just change per website only. not per store or per store view.

---

### **As per official document**

> The scope of the base currency that is used for product prices can be
> configured to apply at either the global or website level. If applied
> to the global level, the same price is used throughout the store
> hierarchy. If applied to the website level, the same product can be
> available at different prices from stores that are associated with
> different websites. By default, the scope of product pricing is
> global.

https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/catalog-price-scope.html

Comment: Right....... +1

Comment: my mistake. thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You are welcome @nhatlich

Comment: Yeah @ronakrathod